# Solidity - How to call smart contract instances from external contract?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, embark

I have created an AccountManager smart contract and two instances of it(PARTYA and PARTYB).
When calling TransferAgent.transfer(AccountManager.address, AccountManager.address) I can see accounts[msg.sender].balance update as expected.
However, when calling the instances(PARTYA and PARTYB), for example, TransferAgent.transfer(PARTYA.address, PARTYB.address) there is no change reflected in the balance.

I have spent some time researching how to call AccountManager (instances) from TransferAgent (external contract) using addresses, but could not find anything specific to this.  I am not able to get balance to reflect change.  Any suggestions?

Environment
- Ethereum
- embark-framework
- Solidity

My setup is below

contracts.json

```
    {
      "default": {
        "gas": "auto",
        "contracts": {
          "SimpleStorage": {
            "args": [
              100
            ]
          },
          "Agent" : {
            "args": [
            ]
          },
          "AccountManager" : {
            "args": [
            ]
          },
          "PARTYA" : {
            "instanceOf" : "AccountManager",
            "args" : [
            ]       
          },
          "PARTYB" : {
            "instanceOf" : "AccountManager",
            "args" : [
            ]       
          },
          "TransferAgent" : {
            "args": [
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Agent.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Agent {
/* Define variable owner of the type address*/
address owner;

/* this function is executed at initialization and sets the owner of the contract */
function Agent() { owner = msg.sender; }

/* Function to recover the funds on the contract */
function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) selfdestruct(owner); }
}

contract AccountManager is Agent {
enum ACTIVE { Y, N } 
enum STATUS { CREDIT, DEBIT }
mapping (address => Account) public accounts;

struct Account {
    bytes32 ssn;
    int balance;
    ACTIVE active;
    STATUS status;
}

modifier withdrawValidation(int withdrawAmt) {
    if( withdrawAmt <= accounts[msg.sender].balance)  {
        throw;
    }
    _;
}

// Check for current account matching 
modifier transferValidation(address _from, address _to, bytes32 _ssn) {
    if( AccountManager(_from).getSSN() != _ssn || 
            AccountManager(_to).getSSN() != _ssn || 
                AccountManager(_from).getStatus() == STATUS.CREDIT )  {
        throw;
    }
    _;
}

function register(bytes32 _ssn) public returns (bool success) {
    Account memory newRegistree;
    newRegistree.ssn = _ssn;
    newRegistree.balance = 0;
    newRegistree.active = ACTIVE.Y;
    newRegistree.status = STATUS.DEBIT;
    accounts[msg.sender] = newRegistree;
    return true;
}

function update(bytes32 _ssn) public returns (bool success) {
    accounts[msg.sender].ssn = _ssn;
    return true;
}

function deposit(int _depositAmt) public returns(bool success) {
    accounts[msg.sender].balance += _depositAmt;
    return true;
}

function withdraw(int _withdrawAmt) public returns(bool success) {
    accounts[msg.sender].balance = (accounts[msg.sender].balance - _withdrawAmt);
    return true;
}

function getBalance() public constant returns(int balance) {
    return accounts[msg.sender].balance;
}

function setBalance(int _balance) external returns(bool success) {
    accounts[msg.sender].balance = _balance;
    return true;
}

function setStatus() internal {
    if(accounts[msg.sender].balance >= 0)
        accounts[msg.sender].status = STATUS.DEBIT;
    else 
        accounts[msg.sender].status = STATUS.CREDIT;
}

function getStatus() external constant returns (STATUS status) {
    return accounts[msg.sender].status;
}

function getSSN() external constant returns(bytes32 ssn) {
    return accounts[msg.sender].ssn;
}

function getAccount() public constant returns (bytes32 ssn, int balance, ACTIVE active, STATUS status) {
    return (accounts[msg.sender].ssn, accounts[msg.sender].balance, accounts[msg.sender].active, accounts[msg.sender].status);
}
}

contract TransferAgent is Agent {
function transfer(address _from, address _to) public returns (bool success) {
    AccountManager(_from).setBalance(100); // not working for instances PARTYA,PARTYB
    AccountManager(_to).setBalance(200); // not working for instances PARTYA,PARTYB    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very minimalist example that just concentrates on sending a transaction to another contract.

The "Hub" will deploy two "Spokes" and then you can use `function local()` to send messages to one of the spokes. Events are logged on both sides so you can see what's going on.

```
contract Hub {

  Spoke public A;
  Spoke public B;

  event LogTXNSent(address spoke);

  function Hub() {
    A = new Spoke();
    B = new Spoke();
  }

  function local(address spokeAddress)
    public
    returns(bool success)
  {
    if(spokeAddress != address(A) && spokeAddress != address(B)) throw;
    if(!Spoke(spokeAddress).logEvent()) throw;
    LogTXNSent(spokeAddress);
    return true;
  }

}

contract Spoke {

  event LogTXNFrom(address sender);

  function logEvent()
    public
    returns(bool success)
  {
    LogTXNFrom(msg.sender);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.